# Error running React App "about the webpack"

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). When I run `npm start`, I get the error below.

I've tried all the steps given by the terminal (see below). It just doesn't work. I have also tried to uninstall and install webpack, but no luck so far. How can I fix this?

> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is
>   likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix
>   locally.
>          The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a    dependency:
>
> ```
>  "webpack": "4.19.1"
>    Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it    automatically. However, a different version of webpack was detected
> ```
>
> higher up in the tree:
>
> ```
>  /Users/seertech/node_modules/webpack (version: 4.23.1)
>    Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause    hard-to-debug issues.
>    If prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an    .env file in your project. That will permanently disable this
> ```
>
> message    but you might encounter other issues.
>          To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the    exact order:
>
> ```
>  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
>  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
>  3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
>  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
>    In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem. If this has    not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
>
>  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
>     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
>
>  6. Check if /Users/seertech/node_modules/webpack is outside your project directory.
>     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
>
>  7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
>     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.
>    If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file    in your project. That would permanently disable this preflight
> ```
>
> check    in case you want to proceed anyway.
>          P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-)    We hope you find them helpful!
>          npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! react-client@0.1.0    start: `react-scripts start` npm ERR! Exit
>   status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!    Failed at the react-client@0.1.0 start
>   script. npm ERR! This is    probably not a problem with npm. There is
>   likely additional logging    output above.

Comment: Can you please properly format your question? Right now it is hard to read and understand what your problem is.

Comment: I am so sorry sir, its an errror from the mac terminal

Comment: You need to provide more information.

Comment: Perhaps you have installed webpack globally? Try `npm uninstall -g webpack`.

Comment: @petezurich The question is properly formatted IMO – the whole yellow part is a quote of the error message that is shown by create-react-app

Comment: @PatrickHund Well, yes. Now it is... I just did the formatting... ;0)

Comment: What version of node are you running?

Comment: @Javaslayer did you try uninstalling webpack globally like I suggested? I had the same problem, and that was the cause

Comment: I  tried to uninstall the webpack and react-app and install and restart, ad it works.. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because an NPM package was installed in a folder above this one, likely in error. To remedy, start at the project folder and `cd ../` into the above folder, do `ls`. If you see a node_modules folder that shouldn't be there, delete it. If not, `cd ../` again and `ls` again. Repeat until you find the offending node_modules and delete it.